# How do I fix the ValueError: Could not open '/mobilenet_v2_1.0_224_quant_edgetpu.tflite'. on the Coral Dev board?

Tags: valueerror, google-coral

I was following coral.ai tutorial on USB camera use and loaded the models, text-files and etc a couple days ago. When I came back to my project today and tried to run the model again, the program presented this error `ValueError: Could not open '/mobilenet_v2_1.0_224_quant_edgetpu.tflite'.`
and I don't know what to do because I haven't moved anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try running the [example](https://coral.ai/docs/dev-board/camera/#run-a-demo-with-the-camera) after executing this command:
export DEMO_FILES="$HOME/demo_files"